# How to Modify the Labels on a KendoUI Slider Ticks?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, kendo-ui

I am using the KendoUi Slider. I'm using the following setings:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#slider").kendoSlider({
            increaseButtonTitle: "Right",
            decreaseButtonTitle: "Left",
            showButtons: false,
            min: 1,
            max: 4,
            smallStep: .2,
            largeStep: 1,
            value: <%= TotalScore %>,
            tooltip:
                {
                    enabled:false
                }  
        });
```

I have four large steps and I want to label each of them "P" "O" "G" "I" in place of the numbers. How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I couldn't find anything in the settings that would allow for this. So, I just built a quick slider item modifier instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/QwGUy/1/

Comment: Brilliant example - thank you!  Any idea on how to do this using the AngularJs KendoUI style?  Have everything wired up for Angular to get the slider control working - but not sure about the corollary on the overriding the labels.  Know it's a long shot - but worth the question.